# Existe alguma ferramenta para ver um website em todos os tamanhos de ecra?

Tags: layout-responsivo

Estou a fazer um website responsivo mas acontece que preciso de uma ferramenta para poder ver se está ficando bem em todos os tamanhos de ecra.

Alguma sugerencia?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o próprio console do Google Chrome.
Ao apertar F12 (Abrir o console), você pode clicar no ícone da imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após, no topo, você pode utilizar a opção de diversos tamanhos e também neste local você pode utilizar as opções de telas de diversos dispositivos, assim verificando a responsividade do seu site.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você pode acessar o site [Quirktools](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/) e selecionar os diversos tamanhos e dispositivos caso, não esteja familiarizado com os recursos do próprio navegador.